# Which JavaScript Primitives are Immutable in the Heap?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection, allocation, primitive-types

I've been reading into methods for reducing the effects of JavaScript garbage collection on real-time applications, and I've found a lot of conflicting information about how primitives are stored.  [This article](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596101996/ch04.html) suggests that Strings are the only immutable primitive.  However, [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) suggests that all types are immutable.

What I'm really trying to understand here is whether there are types that can be used which will not cause the memory manager to do any allocations, or if changing a variable always causes it's value to be allocated anew and it's old value to be collected.  I just can't seem to find any conclusive evidence.  Maybe there is no one answer, but if someone has any information to point me to, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: All `primitives` except `Object` are immutable. `String` is a primitive type. The first link does not say that other primitive types are mutable. It just talks about strings.

Comment: @BatScream - Please post a reference that explains how numbers and booleans are immutable and what that even means for that type of primitive.

Comment: @jfriend00 - please refer the Mozilla developer page linked to by the op.

Comment: @BatScream - It's pretty much meaningless to say a number or a boolean is immutable.  It doesn't affect how you program in any way since booleans and numbers are assigned by a copy anyway so there are no references to them so lack of mutability doesn't really change anything.  With strings, it's useful to know they are immutable, but that really just explains why not a single string method is capable of changing the current string, they all just return new strings.  Again, it doesn't really change how you program because there are no methods that can change a string anyway.

Comment: It is likely (though not in a specification and totally up to an implementation) that assigning a boolean to an already existing variable does not require any extra memory allocations, that the boolean fits right into the core space allocated for the variable.  In fact, I think I've read that about Chrome's internal memory structure, but I don't have a reference handy.